# Why does my WPF TextBox not show any characters?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, textbox, wpf-controls

I have an application which includes a DLL written in WPF. This application starts with the login window (the application is a Windows Form and the DLL is in WPF). When I type the user name or password I can't see the characters in the textbox, but they are saved in the `Text`1 property of both the textBox or the passwordBox as expected.

What could explain this behavior, and how can I fix it so that I see the characters as they're typed?

Comment: Can you see the text box's border and blinking cursor? Does the blinking cursor move as you type? A screenshot might help, even if only to rule out some of the more obscure possibilities. So might the code you use to show the WPF control -- is it a WPF Window, or a WPF UserControl hosted in a Form via ElementHost?

Comment: It would be really helpful if you could provide us with some code samples. Otherwise we're taking shots in the dark.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe could it be the foreground color which is equal to the background color ?  If you try selecting text after typing, do you get something ?

Answer (score 0):

the foreground and the background are not the same, i have checked it...
i get the text i type in but i can't see it, this is the most weird thing i have ever seen....i have opened another project

Comment: Use the "add comment" link to respond to individual answers.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen this in your scenario: when the WPF window is hosted from a Windows Form application.

You need to run the WPF window in a separate thread to avoid this problem.